# SOSL Query against Custom setting object

Tags: customsetting, sosl

I am experiencing some inconsistent behavior.  On one org - I'm doing a SOSL (Search Query) against a custom setting and it works fine.  But on a different org - I get entity type My_Custom_Setting__c does not support search.

Did I forget to configure something?  I'm not sure why it works on one org and not another.  This happens in the developer console - so we are not even talking about code yet.  Just a straight SOSL query.

FIND {name} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING MY_Custom_Setting__c (id, name)

Comment: Are you running the query as the same profile in both orgs? Same API Version?

Comment: Whats the visibility of custom settings ? Is it protected?

Comment: Yes, the custom settings are protected - but that's the same in both orgs.  And since they are dev orgs - I'm always logged in as the system admin user.

Comment: both orgs are List Settings ?

Comment: yes - the orgs are deployed through our Jenkins/Ant scripts - on a nightly basis from the sale code base.    Based on what people have been saying it seems to be that this should work - you should be able to run SOSL queries against the custom settings - right now I've just switched to SOQL and that works ok for now

Answer (score -1):

I think in one org you didn't have it enabled, it's something that must be turned on in setup.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O_rn9r4O_1o